# IntelliJ IDEA Mercurial Push Hangs

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial, jetbrains-ide

I have a local IntelliJ IDEA project that is configured to use Mercurial version control at bitbucket.org. I can commit files locally (Ctrl+K) and it registers my changes, but when I try to do a push (Ctrl+Shift+K), it never completes.

I have successfully committed/pushed changes to this bitbucket repository before. The "hang on push" is occurring with IDEA v13.1.2 (135.690), but I rolled back to the v13.1 (135.667) build and I'm experiencing the same thing. The last time I did a successful push was 2014-03-21.

The Background Tasks pane shows an "Pushing..." status. Occasionally, a "Checking incoming a & outgoing changes..." status pops up underneath that.

My Version Control Console looks like...

```
hg.exe branches 
hg.exe incoming --template {rev}{node}{author}{desc|firstline} --quiet --newest-first
hg.exe outgoing --template {rev}{node}{author}{desc|firstline} --quiet --newest-first
hg.exe push https://myUserName@bitbucket.org/myUserName/myProjectName
hg.exe incoming --template {rev}{node}{author}{desc|firstline} --quiet --newest-first
hg.exe outgoing --template {rev}{node}{author}{desc|firstline} --quiet --newest-first
hg.exe incoming --template {rev}{node}{author}{desc|firstline} --quiet --newest-first
hg.exe outgoing --template {rev}{node}{author}{desc|firstline} --quiet --newest-first
...
```

I first opened up a support ticket (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/27715) with JetBrains, but their email suggested maybe looking for help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a response from JetBrains and was ablr to resolve my issue.

As a workaround, I created a `%HOME%\.hgrc` file and included my authentication information there.

```
[auth]
bb.prefix = https://bitbucket.org
bb.username = {username}
bb.password = {password}
```

See also,

- http://hgtip.com/tips/beginner/2009-09-30-configuring-mercurial/
- http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-10-01-configuring-user-auth-https/